# Potential SetFocus() issue

Tags: setfocus, pywinauto

## I think SetFocus() still has some issues, follow below steps to reproduce:

'''Open Notepad and have it as Background window and Make Chrome or IE as Active Window and run the below script.
Observation: it does the first click on Chrome or IE before returning Notepad window and follows steps in script.'''

```
app = pywinauto.Application()
window = app.Window_(title_re='Untitled - Notepad')
window.SetFocus()
window['Edit'].ClickInput()
window.TypeKeys("Test")
```